# Convert object to string in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried several different ways of converting $dollars from object to string in the function get_dollars- but no success. This is what var_dump says:

```
dollars: object(stdClass)#4 (1) {
  ["dollars"]=>
  string(2) "10"
}
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
<GetDollars>c__Iterator2C:MoveNext() (at Assets/MultiOnline/UMA/Example/Scripts/UMACharacterCustomization.cs:249)
```

And this is the code:

UMACharacterCustomization.class.php

```
 <?php
//MOPlayer: manage all interactions with the player_name MySQL table
Class UMACharacterCustomization extends MODb{
    //character name
    private $name;
    private $errorMessage=null;
    private $dollarMessage;
    private $euroMessage=null;
        private $dollars=null;
        private $euros=null;

    // Constructor
    function __construct($user, $pass, $host, $dbName){
        parent::__construct($user, $pass, $host, $dbName);
    }

    // Destructor
    function __destruct(){
        parent::__destruct();
    }

    // Getter
    public function __get($nom){
        if(isset($this->$nom)){
            return $this->$nom;
        }
    }

    //Save the player_name
    public function playername($name,$user_name){
        if(!empty($name)&&!empty($user_name)){
            $this->name->$name;
            $this->user_name->$user_name;
            $array = array(
                        ':player_id' => '',
                        ':player_name' => secure_prepare_db($name),
                        ':userName' => secure_prepare_db($user_name)
                    );
        //  $array=array(':player_id' => '',
//':player_name' => secure_prepare_db($this->$name));

            $this->prepare_exec('INSERT INTO players(player_id,player_name,userName) VALUES(:player_id,:player_name,:userName)', $array);
        }else{
$this->errorMessage.= $name;
}
        return false;
    }


public function get_dollars($user_name){
        if(!empty($user_name)){
$this->user_name->$user_name;
            $array=array(':userName' => secure_prepare_db($user_name));

$dollars = $this->query_fetchObject('SELECT dollars FROM
                    players WHERE userName=\''.$user_name.'\'');

$this->dollarMessage.= (string)$dollars ; 

        }else{
$this->errorMessage.= $user_name;
}
    }

    public function get_euros($user_name){
        if(!empty($user_name)){
$this->user_name->$user_name;
            $array=array(':userName' => secure_prepare_db($user_name));

$euros = $this->query_fetchObject('SELECT euros FROM
                    players WHERE userName=\''.secure_db($user_name).'\'');


$this->euroMessage.= ''+ $euros ; 

        }else{
$this->errorMessage.= $user_name;
}
    }
}
?>
```

Would appreciate your help

Comment: Where are you trying to convert it?  I see no conversion, you're using a fetch object method then expecting it to be a string?  Why?  The var dump shows the string is at `$dollars->dollars`

Comment: Also, in your `get_dollars` method, you are open to sql injection. You aren't doing any sort of prepare/bind/escape to the `$user_name` variable. You shouldn't be concatenating variables into queries at all. You should prepare a query with placeholders and then bind the variables to those placeholders. I don't know what `secure_db` is trying to do, but I would bet it is anything but "secure".

Comment: `$this->dollarMessage.= $dollars->dollars;` maybe???

Comment: Devon, I just have replaced $this->dollarMessage.= (string)$dollars ;  with $this->dollarMessage.= var_dump($dollars) ; before pasting here and didn't notice. Thanks a lot, now I see, it's because of fetch object. I guess I have to use fetch row

Comment: Jonathan Kuhn, thanks a lot